# Getting Non-Type error while trying to find the determinant of an N*N matrix

Tags: python, function, matrix, determinants, non-type

I am trying to make a program to find the determinant of an N*N matrix and here is my code:

```
from copy import deepcopy

n = input()
myMatrix = []

for i in range(n):
    myMatrix.append(raw_input().split())

def findMinor(matrix, i):
    minor = deepcopy(matrix)
    del minor[0]
    for b in range(len(matrix)-1):
        del minor[b][i]
    return minor

def det(matrix):
    determinant = 0
    if len(matrix) == 1:
        determinant = matrix[0][0]
    else:
        for x in range(len(matrix)):
            coFactor = det(findMinor(matrix,x))
            determinant += int(matrix[0][x]) * (-1)**(2+x) * coFactor
            return determinant

print det(myMatrix)
```

I am getting No-Type error and I'm pretty sure its because I'm calling a function within itself since it is a recursive approach.

Is there any way to fix this? Possibly even dump the second function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `det` only returns something in the `else` part of the `if.. else`

If `len(matrix)==1`, nothing happens (or at least nothing is returned).  So when `n=2` it tries to use `cofactor` which should be the result from an `n=1` calculation, the value of `cofactor` is `None`.

so remove the indentation before `return determinant` so it's out of the `if.. else..` part of the code.

Even after fixing this, you'll have other problems.  You'd be better off storing your matrix as a lot of floats rather than strings.  If you want to leave it as strings, make `determinant=int(matrix[0][0])`

I think the best way to fix the string issue is:

```
for i in range(n):
    myMatrix.append(map(float,raw_input().split()))
```

And for what it's worth, if you want to really do matrix calculations, don't use your own data structures.  Use numpy - it will be faster than anyone could write in pure python.